# Linear programming - How to write this objective function with a lot of summations to matlab?

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

[image]

How do you code this objective function with many summations using Matlab?

I only found examples that are applicable to obj function with no summations.

The decision variables are the ff: x, y, w, z
The parameters are the ff: r, c1, c2, i

Comment: You have to hold shift to utilise the `+` key on most keyboards, just to the left of the backspace key. Jokes aside what is your specific confusion? What have you tried? Can you do a single summation using a `for` loop or an array and go from there? You might want to take the [tour] and read [ask], before [edit]ing your question to narrow down the specific issue you're having in terms of a [mcve]

Comment: The first question is which symbols in the formula denote variables (that the optimization should search) and which denote constant coefficients (fixed model parameters)

Comment: See: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-expressions.html